# How can I use Autoit to close all javascript alerts and confirmations that may appear?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, alerts, autoit

I am testing in selenium and I have a bunch of stuff that happens on page load. I found out about autoit, and I was thinking that it could handle all javascript dialog issues. I was searching around the web for some autoit script that could handle this...

Other options would be helpful as well!

I don't necessarily need all the code, but some point in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright so this solution works for me... I was able to close 2 windows here. Also I will be able to handle popups based on their name which is cool. It always runs in the background after I have lauched the script. When I want it to end I simply close autoit from task manager or from the task bar area on the right.

```
While True
If WinWait('Name of your Popup', '', 1) == 1 Then
    ;Wait for page to load if found
    Sleep(10000)
    ;Close Page
    Send('!{F4}') 
    Sleep(5000)
    ;Confirm Dialog
    Send('{ENTER}') 
    Sleep(1000)
    ;Close Lanucher Page
    Send('!{F4}') 
    Sleep(5000)
    ;Confirm Dialog
    Send('{ENTER}') 
EndIf
;Let another thread have a turn
sleep(3)
WEnd
```

Also this is possible from directly within python, details: http://www.parrisstudios.com/?p=308, but you still need autoit3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues with alert boxes you might want to disable them programmatically or create a separate mode in your code that would turn them off based on a condition (i.e. debug mode).

Macro recording programs don't work as well as you might think. Typically macro-recording programs record locations of mouse clicks and timing of key presses. The better macro-recording programs use (typically image processing) and (rarely) computer vision techniques. The solutions that use these techniques are typically VERY EXPENSIVE. (5k-10k per seat) [I can't remember one of the names of the better versions [Might be QuickTest](https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-127-24%5E1352_4000_100__), but it was made by a company that was bought out by HP]

Comment: well its not simply about ignoring it the dialog... it needs to always select ok. Perhaps I could set up a pluggin in firefox that always confirms, but alerts and confirmations are based on the OS not on the browser, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to interact with a webpage with autoit and the stupid javascript alerts kept breaking everything and I finally figured out how to disable them so I thought I would post it here:

```
#include <ie.au3>

$oIE = _IEAttach('https://www.site.com','URL')

$EventObject=ObjEvent($oIE.document,"IEEvent_")
Func IEEvent_onreadystatechange()
    $readystate=$oIE.document.readystate
    ConsoleWrite ($readystate & @CRLF )
    if $readystate='interactive' then killalert()
EndFunc

while 1
    sleep(100)
WEnd

func killalert()
Local $o_head = $oIE.document.all.tags("HEAD").Item(0)
Local $o_script = $oIE.document.createElement("script")
With $o_script
    .language = "jscript"
    .type = "text/javascript"
    .text = 'function alert(message) {};'
EndWith
$o_head.appendChild($o_script)
EndFunc
```

Basically what this does is have a function get called in autoit when the page ready status='interactive' (apparently this is after most of the page has loaded but before it "runs" anything i think) that inserts some javascript into the page to redefine the alert() function so that it does nothing (no alert dialog to worry about having to click ok on). I have tested this and it works.

If you have the alert() function being called from a frame inside the page then you will have to use the onreadystatechange event and the readystate property of the frame instead of the main document.